# RN 171 (RN-XV Wifly) scan and connect to another IBSS Ad-Hoc Network

Tags: wifi, wifly

My setup is as follows:

1. A Raspberry Pi + Realtek WiFi Dongle. It is configured as an IBSS Ad-Hoc Network (SSID = "pi-adhoc"). This works so far. I can find this network and connect to it from my laptop, even create TCP Sessions and send/receive data, etc..
2. A RN-XV Wifly Module connected to a STM32F via UART.

What I want to do is, that I want the Wifly to connect to the Pi's Ad-Hoc Network. The first step was to set PIN9 of the module to "high" i.o. to have the Module itself create an Ad-Hoc network. I connected and opened a Telnet connection to configure the module. I then triggered the Wifly's scan with the "scan"-command. The Problem is, that my "pi-adhoc" network is not found by the Wifly while all other devices (Laptop, Smartphone, ...) do find it.

Maybe someone had the same issue and can help me with this.

Edit: 
For those stumbling upon this question later on. Found out that firmware 2.32 does not support adhoc mode. Updated to version 2.36 and successfully scanned my "pi-adhoc" network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one else seems to have something to say, i'm writing this answer. Please look at the edit of the question concerning the module's firmware.